Import spaCy KeyError: '__reduce_cython__'
While trying to import spaCy in my jupyter notebook, I encountered this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 7
      4 import seaborn as sns
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 7 import spacy
      8 import medspacy

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py:13
     10 # These are imported as part of the API
     11 from thinc.api import Config, prefer_gpu, require_cpu, require_gpu  # noqa: F401
---> 13 from . import pipeline  # noqa: F401
     14 from . import util
     15 from .about import __version__  # noqa: F401

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py:2
      1 from .attributeruler import AttributeRuler
----> 2 from .dep_parser import DependencyParser
      3 from .edit_tree_lemmatizer import EditTreeLemmatizer
      4 from .entity_linker import EntityLinker

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\dep_parser.pyx:1, in init spacy.pipeline.dep_parser()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\transition_parser.pyx:1, in init spacy.pipeline.transition_parser()

KeyError: '__reduce_cython__'

Similar questions regarding reduce_cypthon had different errors, such as AttributeError, that couldn't be resolved with this particular error. My spaCy was importing yesterday without issues. Please help me resolve.
